# how to plot mid point in between branch points and end points

Tags: matlab, image-processing, pattern-matching

this is my image i already find out the end points and branch points but i want to plot a point in between these two point because i will help me to add edges between to points. please give me some code to find the mid points or centroid between two points.

```
clc;
clear all;
% read in a sample image -- also see letters.png, bagel.png
J=imread('ds2.jpg');

% Normalize and Binarization
b = imresize(J,[100,100]);
th = graythresh(b);
BW1 = im2bw(b, th);
figure;
imshowpair(b, BW1, 'montage');

% the standard skeletonization:

 skelimg = bwmorph(~BW1,'thin',inf);

 mn = bwmorph(skelimg,'branchpoints');
 [row, column] = find(mn);
 branchpts = [row column];


 Endimg = bwmorph(skelimg,'endpoints');
 [row,column] = find(Endimg);
 Endpts = [row column];

 figure;imshow(skelimg);

 hold on;

 plot(branchpts(:,2),branchpts(:,1),'g*');
 plot(Endpts(:,2),Endpts(:,1),'g*');
 hold on;
```

[reference image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/827Jh.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bwdistgeodesic` ([helpful link](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2011/12/13/exploring-shortest-paths-part-5/)) can help you with that. you can do something like that:

```
clc;
clear all;
% read in a sample image -- also see letters.png, bagel.png
J=im2double(imread('circles.png'));

% Normalize and Binarization
b = imresize(J,[100,100]);
th = graythresh(b);
BW1 = im2bw(b, th);
figure;
imshowpair(b, BW1, 'montage');

% the standard skeletonization:
skelimg = bwmorph(BW1,'thin',inf);

mn = bwmorph(skelimg,'branchpoints');
[row, column] = find(mn);
branchpts = [row column];


Endimg = bwmorph(skelimg,'endpoints');
[row,column] = find(Endimg);
Endpts = [row column];

n = size(Endpts,1);
Cntrpts = zeros(n,2);
for ii = 1:n
    % compute end & branch points geodesic distance transform
    dEnd = bwdistgeodesic(skelimg, Endpts(ii,2), Endpts(ii,1), 'quasi-euclidean');
    [~,closestBranchIdx] = min(dEnd(mn));
    dStart = bwdistgeodesic(skelimg, branchpts(closestBranchIdx,2), branchpts(closestBranchIdx,1), 'quasi-euclidean');
    D = dStart + dEnd;
    D = round(D * 8) / 8;
    D(isnan(D)) = inf;
    paths = imregionalmin(D);
    % compute geodesic distance on found path from end point and divide max distance by 2 for center point
    dCenter = bwdistgeodesic(paths, Endpts(ii,2), Endpts(ii,1), 'quasi-euclidean');
    dCenter(isinf(dCenter)) = nan;
    c = nanmax(dCenter(:)) / 2;
    [~,idx] = nanmin(abs(dCenter(:) - c));
    [yc,xc] = ind2sub(size(dCenter),idx);
    Cntrpts(ii,:) = [yc,xc];
end

figure;imshow(skelimg);
hold on;
plot(Cntrpts(:,2),Cntrpts(:,1),'ro')

plot(branchpts(:,2),branchpts(:,1),'g.');
plot(Endpts(:,2),Endpts(:,1),'b.');
hold on;
disp(B)
```

EDIT - centers between all detected points:

```
Allpts = [Endpts;branchpts]; % all possible points
n = size(Allpts,1);
Cntrpts = nan(n^2,2);
for ii = 1:n
    for jj = [1:(ii-1) (ii+1):n]            
        % distance from start & end points
        dEnd = bwdistgeodesic(skelimg, Allpts(ii,2), Allpts(ii,1), 'quasi-euclidean');
        dStart = bwdistgeodesic(skelimg, Allpts(jj,2), Allpts(jj,1), 'quasi-euclidean');
        D = dStart + dEnd;
        D = round(D * 8) / 8;
        D(isnan(D)) = inf;
        if all(isinf(D)) % seed points not connected
            Cntrpts(ii,:) = [nan nan];
        end
        % distance of center point (just half the distance)
        paths = imregionalmin(D);
        dCenter = bwdistgeodesic(paths, Allpts(ii,2), Allpts(ii,1), 'quasi-euclidean');
        dCenter(isinf(dCenter)) = nan;
        c = nanmax(dCenter(:)) / 2;
        [~,idx] = nanmin(abs(dCenter(:) - c));
        [yc,xc] = ind2sub(size(dCenter),idx);
        Cntrpts((ii-1)*n + jj,:) = [yc,xc];
    end
end
figure;imshow(skelimg);
hold on;
plot(Cntrpts(:,2),Cntrpts(:,1),'r.')
plot(branchpts(:,2),branchpts(:,1),'g.');
plot(Endpts(:,2),Endpts(:,1),'b.');
```

Comment: if is it possible to plot center in between to branch points or two end points  ??

Comment: sure. just put other seed points as arguments in the lines defining `dEnd` and `dStart`. note that two seed points which are not connected (on the binary `skelimg`) will result an `inf` for disance and so the center will be plotted in `(1,1)` - because `D` will be nothing but `inf`'s.

Comment: i added a piece of code to compute centers between *all* detected points. if you want just some of them you should determine for which pairs of points this is required.

Comment: i am getting branch,End and center points is there any method to connect these points?? Because i want add these points into a resulting graph and also i want to add the edges to nodes please give me some code.